# Has anyone else suddenly experienced 403 Forbidden errors from the Google Documents List API?

Tags: google-docs-api

After running smoothly for an entire year, [a 'create' call](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_a_new_document_or_file_with_metadata_only) to the Google Documents List API started giving `403 Forbidden` errors.

[Other methods](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files) work fine with the same `access_token` parameter. This started around December 7th very consistently across all of our users invoking this call.

This API just recently got a deprecation policy where it will stay intact until April 2015. To be fair, I don't expect the Google Drive team to be actively supporting this API, but wondering if there is a chance that something on the Google Drive transition could be related to this inconsistency.

Is anyone else experiencing unexpected errors on the Google Documents List API? Any clues as to what is going on, and how deep might the issue be?

Thank you!